# Closures of sets in norms

Tags: real-analysis

a) $(\mathbb{R}^2,\Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$, $U=(0,1]\times(0,1]$

b) $(\mathbb{R}^2,\Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$, $U = \mathbb{R} \cap B(0,1) $

c) $(C[-1,-1],\Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$, $U = \mathbb{P}_{12}$

I know that for a), $cl(0,1)$ is $[0,1]$ does this mean the answer is $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: and for b) is it just [0,1]?

Comment: No. It is $[0,1] \times \{0\}.$

Comment: Alright thanks. I do not have an idea what is c)

Comment: If $X$ is a normed space and if $U$ is a subspace of $X$ with $ dim U < \infty,$ then $U$ is closed, hence $cl(U)=U.$